# Как создать такие графики

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, canvas

Мне надо сделать 2 графика для сайта. Какие есть инструменты, чтобы быстро их осуществить.

1 график с массива {день : кол-во побед}:

[image: 1 график]

2 график.

[image: 2 график]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/
Читайте пользуйтесь, очень много полезного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) простая, но гибкая js-библиотека для построения графиков для дизайнеров и разработчиков